# Wordpress - qTranslate image description

Tags: wordpress, media, qtranslate

I have a WP website based mostly on a gallery of images, with the description of each image.
I'm using qTranslate as I need the site in two languages, but I can't seem to find a way to translate the image descriptions in the media library.
Anyone knows how, except for reuploading the entire gallery all over again? (500+ images)

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't tried it, but what happens if you put the image description in the form (eg) `[:en]English Description[:fr]French description`?  That's worked for me in other places.

Comment: Failing that, if the description field allows HTML, the form `<!--:en-->English description<!--:--><!--:fr-->French description<!--:-->` might work

Answer (score 0):

As Hobo answered, you can use the HTML comment tag inside the Description of image field. as

```
<!--:en-->English description<!--:--><!--:fr-->French description<!--:-->
```

If it doesn't work there is a workaround and forcing the description to be read. I have already answered before for a similar problem so I am just linking it here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51946/qtranslate-get-content-by-language

If you still cannot figure out how to solve then comment below and I will be glad to help out.